# How to load Widget in react js class

Tags: reactjs, widget

Unable to display a widget in my react class the widget link is: [For a proper code in HTML and  script][1]https://in.tradingview.com/widget/market-overview/
I am not getting any error but the widget is not displaying. Kindly do see the widget link

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
            <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
            <div className="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://in.tradingview.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span className="blue-text">Market Data</span></a> by TradingView</div>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js" async dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html:({
                    "showChart": true, "locale": "in", "largeChartUrl": "", "width": "400", "height": "600", "plotLineColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 1)", "plotLineColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 1)",
                    "gridLineColor": "rgba(233, 233, 234, 1)",
                    "scaleFontColor": "rgba(214, 216, 224, 1)",
```

Comment: I think the problem is in  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html:({

Comment: why are you inserting script tag in render , it is totally wrong. you can make another function before render and return the values/html from it.